# SQL query either runs endlessly or returns no values

Tags: sql, sql-server

having trouble with a multi-table query today. I tried writing it myself and it didn't seem to work, so I selected all of the columns in the Management Studio Design view. The code SHOULD work but alas it doesn't. If I run this query, it seems to just keep going and going. I left my desk for a minute and when I came back and stopped the query, it had returned something like 2,000,000 rows (there are only about 120,000 in the PODetail table!!):

```
SELECT     PODetail.OrderNum, PODetail.VendorNum, vw_orderHistory.Weight, vw_orderHistory.StdSqft, vw_orderHistory.ReqDate, vw_orderHistory.City, 
                  vw_orderHistory.State, FB_FreightVend.Miles, FB_FreightVend.RateperLoad
FROM         PODetail CROSS JOIN
                  vw_orderHistory CROSS JOIN
                  FB_FreightVend
ORDER BY ReqDate
```

Not only that, but it seems that every record had an OrderNum of 0 which shouldn't be the case. So I tried to exclude it...

```
SELECT     PODetail.OrderNum, PODetail.VendorNum, vw_orderHistory.Weight, vw_orderHistory.StdSqft, vw_orderHistory.ReqDate, vw_orderHistory.City, 
                  vw_orderHistory.State, FB_FreightVend.Miles, FB_FreightVend.RateperLoad
FROM         PODetail CROSS JOIN
                  vw_orderHistory CROSS JOIN
                  FB_FreightVend
WHERE PODetail.OrderNum <> 0
ORDER BY ReqDate
```

While it executes successfully (no errors), it also returns no records whatsoever. What's going on here? I'm also curious about the query's CROSS JOIN. When I tried writing this myself, I first used "WHERE PODetail.OrderNum = vw_orderHistory.OrderNum" to join those tables but I got the same no results issue. When I tried using JOIN, I got errors regarding "multi-part identifier could not be bound."

Comment: cross join does not seem like the thing you want. try possible LEFT join

Comment: LEFT JOIN gave me the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: you will need to add the actual JOIN conditions also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `cross join` returns a zillion records.  The product of the number of records in each table . . . That might be 10,000 * 100,000 * 100 -- this is a big number.

The one caveat is when a table is empty.  Then the rows in that table is 0 . . . and 0 times anything is 0.  So no rows are returned.  And, no rows might be returned quite quickly.

I think you need to learn what `join` really does in SQL.  Then you need to reimplement this with the correct join conditions.  Not only will the query run faster, but it will return accurate results.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't aware of that. I'll read some literature on the JOIN function. I've done these multi-table queries before and have never run into this issue, but then this isn't the best database I've ever worked with.

Comment: Yeah, some of those off-brand databases just don't respect JOIN commands the same way as the most popular products.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use cross joins especially on large tables. The link below will help.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Also **multi-part identifier could not be bound.** means the column might not exist as defined. Verify the column exists, datatype and it's assigned name for join.

At condition <> 0 all non corresponding values from PODetail will be omited.
Use (Ordernumber <> 0 or Ordernumber is null)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid CROSS JOINS like the plague. Explicitly define your Order, PO and VendorFreight JOINS.